# Почему файл-серверная технология умерла?

Tags: база-данных

Объясните, почему file-server'ная технология умерла? В чем были недостатки и плюсы?

Comment: Постановка вопроса предполагает, что она умерла. Так ли это?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ну... вроде как да, насколько мне известно. Ведь сейчас только client-server. Нет?

Comment: Загляните в любую бухгалтерию.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, т.е. вы как бы говорите мне, что 1С-бухгалтерия до сих пор работает по файл-серверной технологии?

Comment: Кагбе да. В большинстве случаев, я бы сказал.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev хм, понятно. Спасибо большое! Удалю вопрос... на всякий случай!

Comment: Не-не! Не удаляйте! На самом деле, тема умерло-не умерло интересная же. А если отойти от баз данных  — так и вдвойне.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, пожалуй, от баз данных уходить далеко не будем. Вопрос именно по базам данныx

Comment: Основной недостаток - невозможность гранулярного контроля доступа.